# List Filter in Look up

Tags: custom-list, lookup-column, filter, custom-form

I have a list which contains a column for Name and a column for Department

I'm building a secondary list which will contain two look up columns. These looks ups will display the Name column from the first list however what I'm hoping to achieve is having the look up only showing names related to a specific department.

For example:
Look up column 1= Mr.Smith from Finance (Or anyone within Finance)
Look up column 2= Mr.Bloggs from Human Resources (Or anyone within Human Resources)

I have filters for each department in the first list but can't seem to find away to filter the look up. I had a quick google search but only found results for more complex issues and this seems simple enough just think I'm missing something.

If someone could point me in the right direction or offer any advice it'll be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my look-up columns on SP 2013 - I could not filter them.  I know what you mean, it seems like quite a basic thing to be able to configure for a look-up.

I've posted quite a few similar answers to this, so it feels like I'm a secret agent for posting the same thing to 3rd party software (disclaimer - I do not work for Sparqube!).

[Sparqube](http://www.sparqube.com/SharePoint-Lookup-Column/) (and possibly other companies besides them) offer add-in columns which, when installed, will appear on the 'create column' screen.  Their look-up columns mean you can filter the results which you want to be available in your column.  If you so wished you can also make your new lookup column work of a view on your source list.

What you describe in your 2nd paragraph is called 'cascading columns' - it's a bit fiddly to configure at first, but the Sparqube columns can do this.  Actually it looks like the OOTB columns can be used as cascading columns too - [have a look at this MS link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39842.cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for this however I have found a work around sort of.... I have included a calculated column within the 1st list with the formula:

=IF([Department]="Finance",Title,"")

I then use this column for the lookup in list 2. This only shows people from within finance in the dropdown however those in other departments still show just as blanks. Is there anything you can think of to stop those blank values appearing as I have tried a few formulas and got nowhere.

Comment: There's probably a way to do that, but I find the Sharepoint formulae can become quite complicated - you could post a separate question on that, there are quite a few users who answers calculated-columns type questions.  I'm by no means an expert at them!  Personally I'd have a go at using the cascading columns - using the Microsoft link as a starting point, though since you're part way through what you're doing I'd understand the instinct to persevere!

Comment: I'm going to give it a try and have posted another question around my possible work around. A little behind schedule on getting this completed so using the "Throw enough crap at the wall something will stick" approach now haha

Comment: I've managed to get my workaround to work for anyone reading this is in a similar situation and wishes to see how this was achieved please check https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245339/calculated-column-formula-to-hide-blank-values